# Маршрутизация микротиков

Tags: сеть, маршрутизация, mikrotik

Есть 3 роутера
1 Микротика А L2tp server
2 Микротик Б и Ц клиенты

А и Б видят друг друга и другое оборудование в своих сетях
А и Ц видят друг друга но А не видит все что за роутером Ц, только роутер,  а там еще три статик ИП

Comment: Нет вопросов - нет ответов. Маршрутизация не зависит от марки маршрутизатора. Задайте четкий вопрос и, возможно, вы сами на него сможете ответить.

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо прописать маршрут на роутере А с лок. сетью Ц по типу 192.168.0.0/24